# Header line thickness

Tags: header-footer, line

Can anyone explain me why the thickness of the lines under my headings do vary? The lines are normal under "Education", "Book chapter", "Others, "Teaching", "Research Experiences", "Voluntary Work", and "Software".

But they are thick under "Peer-reviewed Publications", "Scholarships and Research Grants", and "Languages".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {currvita}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\thispagestyle{empty} 

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filright}{\thesection}{1em}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}
\date{}
\centering 
\begingroup
\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\textbf{blabla} 
\endgroup

\raggedright
\section*{Education} 

\section*{Peer-reviewed Publications} 

\section*{Book chapter} 

\section*{Others} 

\section*{Teaching} 

\section*{Research Experiences} 

\section*{Voluntary Work}

\section*{Scholarships and Research Grants} 

\section*{Software} 

\section*{Languages}
```

Comment: I think this is only a PDF rendering issue.  If you zoom on the page image, I think you will find the rules are of uniform width.  Thus, the issue, in this case, would not be with LaTeX, but with whatever software you are using to render your PDFs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a PDF rendering issue, not a LaTeX issue.